# Ripple Emulator shows white screen Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Ripple Emulator shows white screen for all Ionic 2 applications. Either running through Visual Studio or through CLI ripple emulate.

Is anybody facing a similar issue?

Does Ripple not support Ionic 2? No relevant documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out ripple issue with VS2015. I first ran the application from CLI using the '`ionic serve`' command. From the browser URL I noted the port application was running on my machine. I assigned the same port in visual studio settings under Tools > Options > Tools For Apache Cordova > Ripple Emulator > uncheck use dynamically assigned port number and add the port number you noted by running `ionic serve` command. Strange VS didn't figure out itself for Ionic v2 as it did for Ionic v1.

I have a similar question open for remote build Ionic 2 application from Visual Studio 2015.2 .

[Ionic 2 application shows white screen on IOS remote build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815587/ionic-2-application-shows-white-screen-on-ios-remote-build)

I have no experience working on MAC and IOS. It would be great If anyone can relate the issues and help me out.