# Ionic 2 application shows white screen on IOS remote build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have created a tabs/sidemenu template application with ionic 2 and --ts as I wanted type script in my project. Whenever I try to remote build the application through Visual Studio 2015 on IOS (device/emulator) a white blank screen is shown. Nothing Happens after it.

I was successfully able to remote build the application with the same configuration for a Ionic 2 blank template and Ionic 1 (tabs/sidemenu/blank)

I have read through the blogs, white screen is a common problem with Ionic 2. Not enough information with remote build.

P.S. All the templates work perfectly fine on Android Emulators and Devices.

Comment: I have a similar answer posted for one of my questions. If anyone can relate the two and help me out. I do not have experience on IOS/MAC   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814531/ripple-emulator-shows-white-screen-ionic-2/36821155#36821155